# In how many ways can $3$ boys and $2$ girls sit in a row, where none of the 3 boys can sit next to an another boy?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

As I see it, the row can only be formed in that way : $BGBGB$ which means that there are $3!\cdot2! = 12$ ways but my book says that the answer is $24$. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Unless the question says something else or we are missing some assumption that is being made I'd say your approach and answer are correct.

Comment: I assumed from the start that they have made a typo in the answer but I wanted to be sure. Another some kind of off-topic question: How can I import Mathjax to a post ?

Comment: No idea sorry, you might find answers [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11864/what-latex-packages-are-used-this-site) or [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6177/what-is-the-relation-between-latex-and-mathjax/).

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Your solution is correct.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to use MathJax on this site.